# How to check if the 1st number is '0' in a string using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple calculator using jQuery.

I have a paragraph tag that I'm using as a display. After pressing 'AC' button that clears my display the paragraph tag contains '0'.

What I wanna do is when I press a button with a number I need this '0' to be replaced with the number I pressed because now it goes like '07' or '05'.

I tried:

```
    $('#7').on('click', function() {
     if ($('#mainline') == '0')) {
       $('#mainline').remove('0');
    }
     $('#mainline').append('7');
    })
```

But I guess I'm doing something wrong. How should I check if #mainline has '0'?

Comment: [`see: charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).  This question has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: You need to use `.text()` or `.val()` to get the contents of `#mainline`, depending on if it's a DIV or an input. And then use `[0]` to get the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#mainline` is a DIV, get its text, then remove leading zeroes with a regexp, then append `7`.

```js
$('#7').click(function() {
  $("#mainline").text(function(i, oldtext) {
    return oldtext.replace(/^0+/, '') + '7';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainline">0</div>
<button id="7">7</button>
```

If it's an input, use `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried this code and it says 'TypeError: oldtext.replace is not a function'

Comment: I always forget that the function has an index argument before the old value. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Using regexp is a good way,but if you do not understand regexp,you can try this:

```
$('#7').on('click', function() {
 if ($('#mainline').text() == '0')) {
   $('#mainline').text('7');
 }else{
   $('#mainline').append('7');
 }
})
```

If '#mainline' is a **input** or **textarea**,use '**val()**' instead of '**text()**'

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to get the value `$('#mainline').text()` then `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` if `$('#mainline').text().indexOf('.') > -1`.

`parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` will automatically remove the excessive ZEROs from head of your string.